# Voting system to choose between two pictures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, voting-system

I am trying to create a voting picture system on rails 3. What I would like to have happen is have two pictures, and have people on the site vote for which one they like more. I know they have a thumbs_up gem, which creates a voting system quickly. Is there a way to either modify the gem to have it work for pictures or is there a simple way to create this?

Comment: What is the hard part? You can show two pictures on the screen, and each picture with a link to the thumbs up vote.

Comment: Can you try to boil this down to an atomic, non-subjective question? Is there a specific issue you are having with the `thumbs_up` gem?

Comment: I guess it would be having it analyze the clicks to show which picture is liked more. Is that involved in thumbs_up?

Comment: What "The social network", you might find the answer with facemash. Kidding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to modify the gem. Just create an appropriate Model for your Images:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voteable
end
```

and for your users:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voter
end
```

after you can compare the upvote count of 2 images with something like:

```
image1.votes_for > image2.votes_for
```